# Correlate TPL task with right thread in WinDbg

Tags: multithreading, task-parallel-library, windbg

We have an application that start some tasks of an array (of System.Threading.Tasks.Task). At the end, it waits the end of tasks using code below:

```
   Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)          
   For Each fator As String In Fatores
                tasks.Add( _
                    Task.Run(Sub()
                                 Calcular(New Object() {fator,})
                             End Sub))
    Next
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())
```

During the execution I extracted a full dump of application. Using !Threads I got list below (finalized was removed).

ID

```
OSID ThreadOBJ           State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count Apt Exception
   0    1 60d8 000000000045e540    26020 Preemptive  000000014DE5FE38:000000014DE5FFD0 00000000004492e0 0     STA 
   2    2 3c90 00000000004896d0    2b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
   5    3 309c 000000001d6ba3f0  102a220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
   7    4 743c 000000001d6eb920  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA 
   8    5 7528 000000001d794080  202b220 Preemptive  000000014DE596F8:000000014DE59FD0 00000000004492e0 0     MTA 
   9    6 53f4 000000001d7bd720    21220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     Ukn 
  10   17 239c 000000001fa04160  202b020 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA 
  12 1134 20ec 0000000000474380  8029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  15  649 2e2c 00000000247fdd00  1029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  17  650 28ac 0000000000478bb0  1029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  16  651 47c8 000000006069d5a0  1029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX  706    0 000000001fb2f9f0  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000004492e0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  22  705 5dd0 000000001fb301c0  1029220 Preemptive  000000014DE5C098:000000014DE5DFD0 00000000004492e0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker)
```

Using command ~*e!clrstack I could find task list at this line

```
000000002083ead0 000007fee6c3bf95 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAllBlockingCore(System.Collections.Generic.List`1, Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 5193]
000000002083eb70 000007fee6c3bbd0 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[], Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 5109]
```

And I got task list in the parameters below

```
0:010> !dumparray 0000000120ca19d8    000000002083eb70 000007fee6c3bbd0 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[], Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 5109]
        PARAMETERS:
            tasks (0x000000002083ec90) = 0x0000000120ca19d8
            millisecondsTimeout (0x000000002083ec98) = 0x00000000ffffffff
            cancellationToken = <no data>
Name:        System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]
MethodTable: 000007fee6f424c8
EEClass:     000007fee5e31238
Size:        72(0x48) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 6, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 000007fee642c650
[0] 0000000120ca1048
[1] 0000000120ca11f0
[2] 0000000120ca1398
[3] 0000000120ca1540
[4] 0000000120ca16e8
[5] 0000000120ca1890
```

Each task have structure below, where appears that only active tasks have the field m_taskID filled

```
0:010> !DumpObj /d 0000000120ca1048
Name:        System.Threading.Tasks.Task
MethodTable: 000007fee642c650
EEClass:     000007fee5e36a30
Size:        72(0x48) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fee6419540  4001a16       38         System.Int32  1 instance            42082 m_taskId
000007fee64170f0  4001a17        8        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_action
000007fee64170f0  4001a18       10        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_stateObject
000007fee64202b8  4001a19       18 ...sks.TaskScheduler  0 instance 0000000003e83d28 m_taskScheduler
000007fee642c650  4001a1a       20 ...eading.Tasks.Task  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_parent
000007fee6419540  4001a1b       3c         System.Int32  1 instance         16982024 m_stateFlags
000007fee64170f0  4001a2e       28        System.Object  0 instance 0000000003e83da8 m_continuationObject
000007fee64247e8  4001a33       30 ...tingentProperties  0 instance 0000000120ca1148 m_contingentProperties
000007fee6419540  4001a14      f30         System.Int32  1   shared           static s_taskIdCounter
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:42084 <<
000007fee6430ac8  4001a15      e80 ...Tasks.TaskFactory  0   shared           static s_factory
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83d80 <<
000007fee64170f0  4001a2f      e88        System.Object  0   shared           static s_taskCompletionSentinel
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83da8 <<
000007fee6439b50  4001a30      f34       System.Boolean  1   shared           static s_asyncDebuggingEnabled
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0 <<
000007fee5d942c8  4001a31      e90 ....Task, mscorlib]]  0   shared           static s_currentActiveTasks
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83dc0 <<
000007fee64170f0  4001a32      e98        System.Object  0   shared           static s_activeTasksLock
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83e10 <<
000007fee6492148  4001a34      ea0 ...bject, mscorlib]]  0   shared           static s_taskCancelCallback
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83e28 <<
000007fee6492288  4001a35      ea8 ...rties, mscorlib]]  0   shared           static s_createContingentProperties
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83e68 <<
000007fee642c650  4001a36      eb0 ...eading.Tasks.Task  0   shared           static s_completedTask
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000000000000 <<
000007fee6492320  4001a37      eb8 ....Task, mscorlib]]  0   shared           static s_IsExceptionObservedByParentPredicate
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83ec0 <<
000007fee6427a38  4001a38      ec0 ...g.ContextCallback  0   shared           static s_ecCallback
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e84910 <<
000007fee64923b0  4001a39      ec8 ...bject, mscorlib]]  0   shared           static s_IsTaskContinuationNullPredicate
                                 >> Domain:Value  00000000004492e0:0000000003e83f00 <<
000007fee642c650  4001a12       28 ...eading.Tasks.Task  0   shared         TLstatic t_currentTask
    >> Thread:Value 60d8:0000000000000000 239c:0000000000000000 2e2c:0000000120ca1540 28ac:0000000120ca16e8 47c8:0000000120ca1890 <<
000007fee649d940  4001a13       30 ....Tasks.StackGuard  0   shared         TLstatic t_stackGuard
    >> Thread:Value 60d8:0000000005d88880 239c:0000000003fbbdd8 2e2c:0000000000000000 28ac:0000000000000000 47c8:0000000000000000 <<
```

I would like to know how to correlate this task with right thread on the list above. The fields t_currentTask and  t_stackGuard at end has all valid threads
, includind STA (Windows Form) where tasks were started. I took a look in another tasks of the array and the last 2 fields are the same in all of them, giiving no clues about related thread. I can identify (by method names in !clrstack of threads) which threads are executing tasks, but I was unable to relate task X thread.
Could anyone help me to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found some Microsoft people who helped me. I can only find it if the thread where the task is running is "alive". Just trace the instance in the heap, as below. However, contrary to what I assumed, the Task objects that were with m_taskId = 0 were the running Tasks. So if there is any process locked waiting for some Task, if I do not find it anywhere it's because it aborted and did not report the status to who was waiting for its conclusion.

```
0:010> !DumpArray /d 0000000120ca19d8
Name:        System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]
MethodTable: 000007fee6f424c8
EEClass:     000007fee5e31238
Size:        72(0x48) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 6, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 000007fee642c650
[0] 0000000120ca1048
[1] 0000000120ca11f0
[2] 0000000120ca1398
[3] 0000000120ca1540
[4] 0000000120ca16e8
[5] 0000000120ca1890
0:010> !gcroot 0000000120ca1890
Thread 239c:
    000000002083ead0 000007fee6c3bf95 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAllBlockingCore(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 5193]
        rbp+10: 000000002083eb70
            ->  0000000120ca1a20 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task, mscorlib]]
            ->  0000000120ca1a48 System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    000000002083eb70 000007fee6c3bbd0 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(System.Threading.Tasks.Task[], Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 5109]
        rbp+10: 000000002083ec90
            ->  0000000120ca19d8 System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
Thread 47c8:
    000000002059e020 000007fee629c686 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2498]
        rbp+10: 000000002059e060
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    000000002059e060 000007fee6274750 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 954]
        r14: 
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    000000002059e160 000007fee629c928 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2827]
        rbp+18: 000000002059e218 (interior)
            ->  0000000120cb0fe8 System.Object[]
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    000000002059e160 000007fee629c928 System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 2827]
        rbp+10: 000000002059e210
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    000000002059e250 000007fee627f74e System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\threadpool.cs @ 820]
        rbp-20: 000000002059e2c0
            ->  0000000120ca1890 System.Threading.Tasks.Task
Found 7 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).
```

That's it